# Reading from xls/xlsx document, which API? Java

Tags: java, excel

Hi i came across http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html and http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ not sure with is more stable and popular.

I will be using this within Spring Framework though particulary Spring Batch. I was hoping that Spring would have an API for such.

You inputs will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache POI API is more popular and updated, as you can see from jexcelapi it only supports up to excel 2003.

Spring does not have an Excel API built in, you would have to use an external one.

Comment: Thanks guys what about 2010? i hope this will be updated soon

Comment: Apache POI supports office 2010 files

Answer (score 0):

Not sure jexcelapi supports xlsx(2007 version), but poi supports both 2003 and 2007 versions of excel.